# Как динамично сохранять ввод текста в select2

Tags: html, select2

Я использую select2. Я использую вот этот код:

```
<link href="https://www.malketiya.com/listgrid/DropDown.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://www.malketiya.com/listgrid/DropDown.js"> </script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" id="selectBox0" onchange="changeFunc0();">
<option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
<option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<script>
var selectedValue1;
var selectedValue0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({tags: true});
});
</script>
```

Параметр tags: true помогает мне вводить текст в input field и фильтровать нужнее значения option.
Как я могу при вводе в input field текста сохранить этот текст. Например я написал символ "f" и он тут же сохранился. То мне использовать Input Event? Но это селектор... Буду очень благодарен и признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: Ура! Я узнал как перехватить событие ввода, но по прежнему не знаю как сохранить символы которые в инпуте, вот код: `$(document).on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function (e) { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

You need make id for

```
<input class="select2-search__field" id="s2sf" type="search".../>
```

and then

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function (e) { 
var x = document.getElementById("s2sf").value; alert(x); 
});
```